# Plugin Installation

Tags: add-on

[image]

I tried to install the plugin.
I did
Edit > Preferences > Addon > Install > I put in the file (ZIP) > it says success, but does not show up. Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: You have text in search box. does addon name start with that? clear text if not

Comment: Also. If this addon is in testing phase, press "Shift" and click "Testing" button to make it also blue.

Answer (score -1):

Click the checkbox "Enabled Add-ons Only"

Comment: I don't see how that should work (at least it doesn't on my computer). When the checkbox is disabled it usually shows enabled _and_ disabled add-ons. If you use this checkbox it only shows the add-ons which are enabled. So if the add-on in question is disabled, it _should_ still show up without this checked, but it will definitely not show up if you use this checkbox.